# Algorithm to encrypt local file such way, that can be decrypted to lots of real-looking results (symmetrical)

Tags: algorithm, security, encryption, cryptography

I have a local file `passwords.txt` where I store all logins and passwords from lots of web-services I personally use

There are some symbols and shortcuts in really critical entries, so it already has some level of security

But I also want to encrypt it from potential remote or physical access, but be able to easily decrypt it when I need to read it or add some

So, I need some script that will take `passwords.txt` and some its own `password`, that will create `encrypted_passwords` file with bytecode inside, that can be easily decrypted by `password`, like:

```
>>> encrypt passwords.txt password
>>> decrypt encrypted_passwords password
```

Encryption algorithm should produce such `encrypted_passwords`, decryption of which with wrong passwords, potentially can produce contents, that can be treated as something real, and then has to be checked only manually

For example, **Me**:

```
>>> cat passwords.txt
example1.com mylogin1 mypassword1
example2.com mylogin2 mypassword2
>>> encrypt passwords.txt password
```

Here comes **Attacker**, that found my `encrypt` and `decrypt` scripts, and:

```
>>> decrypt encrypted_passwords one-of-the-wrong-passwords
>>> cat passwords.txt
example3.com@mylogin3:mypassword3
example4.com@mylogin4:mypassword4
example5.com@mylogin5:mypassword5
```

So the attacker can get something probably even in different length and format, but treat it like: "Hmm, looks real, make sense", when, actually, it has nothing to do with reality

---

So, which algorithm can be used for such purposes and how strong its `password` should be?

I am ready, that password can weight even 100+ megabytes and has to be stored in some other file or multiple files, but will be glad to be able to keep it in mind

P.S. I'll also be glad if there are also some reliable bash or python tools/scripts/libraries

Comment: File1 is  a list of 100,000 websites, file2 is some huge block of random text.  Decrypt selects a website from file1 and a set of indexes into the text to choose letters.

Comment: This is called deniable encryption: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption

Comment: The value of deniability varies according to the specifics of the application. In this case, one might argue that it provides little value, because the attacker just needs to perform the one minor extra step of attempting to authenticate with putative credentials. However, if you had an ultra-secure service that locked out the IP address from which a single failed authentication came from, then maybe the value goes up.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Adding that authentication step would be a large burden to a password cracker, however. Rather than attacking with millions of hashes a second offline, it would have to make a network request for each attempt. That could make many common attacks impractical. (If, however, the attacker knew a single valid credential, it would undermine that protection.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is a lot more trouble than it's worth, but just for the record, this is what you do:

1. Acquire a list of real passwords that you can use to build a statistical model of what real passwords look like;
2. Use that model to build a *compressor*, like a PPM compressor that can compress your password list (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_by_partial_matching).  Compressing your password list with this model will remove all the redundancy and give you a much shorter string of random-looking data.  The compressor and the model will be built into your program.
3. Your encryption program will then compress and encrypt your password list.
4. Now when you decrypt with any password, you'll get a string of random-looking data.  Be sure there are no headers or padding in your encrypted format that would give away whether the data is correct or not.
5. When you decompress *any* string of random-looking data, the model will generate a plausible list of passwords.  The plausibility of this list depends on how good your statistical model is.  Also be sure that your compressed format doesn't include any headers or markers that would indicate whether the decompression is correct or not.

As I said, this is a lot more trouble than it's worth.  Making a good model and a good compressor for this task is quite difficult.